# Errors when starting App project in SwiftUI Xcode 12

Tags: ios, swiftui, xcode12

I cannot start my project since its giving much errors on start.

I just insatlled Xcode latest version from the App Store and i wanted to start learning SwiftUI.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

create a project with a name different to `SwiftUI`

The current target is called `SwiftUI` and when you import `SwiftUI` Xcode confused what to import